# Snowflake Hierarchal

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was able to fetch all employees under the manager and  child employee reporting to those employees 
But I also want to get the root manager's manager row. How can I achieve that

```
    select employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, manager_name
from employee
start  with manager_name = 108
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id
```

[image: Result]

But I was expecting to get the manager's manager too that is as below

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the original source of data that you are using?

Comment: I have used livesql from Oracle

Comment: I meant the data that is in the employee table

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you apply this syntax:

```
CONNECT BY <col_1_identifier> = PRIOR <col_2_identifier>
```

By:

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, manager_name
from employee
start  with manager_name = 108
connect by prior employee_id = Prior manager_id
```

Comment: I got the solution. I am unable to post the answer as I am ban to do that .. Not sure how to come out of the ban

Comment: I used this code and it worked, the only thing I had to do was to remove prior before employee_id in the last line. Thank you